# How can I liquefy egg shell membrane

Tags: biochemistry

I want to extract egg shell membrane from the eggs.
And I want to put them together and turn them into fluid so that I can make whatever shape I want.
Is there any method that can make them into fluid?( like using acid or whatever)

+a egg shell membrane consist of collagen.

Comment: you need to edit your question,a large part of the membrane in eggs are made of keratin.source: https://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/eggs/eggcomposition.html

Comment: some research is expected before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If egg shell membrane really consists of collagen - here is your answer:
Cook it at 160 degrees Fahrenheit (=about 71 degrees Celsius) over a long period of time until it turns into a gel. I am pretty sure it will harden as soon as it is fully cooled down.

"collagen begins to melt at about 160F and turns to a rich liquid,gelatin"

"Denaturation of the collagen molecule is a kinetic process, and hence a function of both temperature and duration of heating. Cooking at low temperatures require long periods of time to liquify collagen."

Source: https://www.scienceofcooking.com/meat/slow_cooking1.htm